# Cannot access child_process API

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have the following tiny `program.js` which tries to execute a binary file:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var path2Binary = '/home/myuser/myproj/bins/mybin';
var par = '--file=' + '/home/myuser/myproj/files/myfile.txt';

var ret = childProcess.execFileSync(path2Binary, [par]);
if (!ret) throw 'Error invoking process!';    
var cnt = ret.stdout;
if (!cnt) throw 'Error retrieving output!';

console.log(cnt);
```

The program tries to execute a binary file and passes it a parameter (a file). The output of this process will be then displayed.

I try to run this: `node program.js`, but get the following

```
var ret = childProcess.execFileSync(path2Binary, [par]);
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'execFileSync'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/myproj/program.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

#### More information

I am running on **CentOS**, *Node* version is **v0.10.36**.

I tried running `sudo yum install nodejs`, but it tells me it is already installed so Node installation looks kinda good.

What's the problem?

#### On a side note...

If I replace `childProcess.execFileSync` with `childProcess.spawn` I get the same.

If I change the first line into the following:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFileSync;
```

Then I get an undefined exception on `exec`.

Comment: What version of node.js?

Comment: It is written in the question... 0.10.36

Comment: Are you sure that version of node.js has the methods you're trying to use? They sure don't seem to be documented. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.36/api/child_process.html

Comment: I see your point... It might be, but strange that yum is not getting the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous child processes aren't supported in node v0.10.36 - https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.36/api/child_process.html

Looks like it may have been introduced in 0.12.

Comment: 0.11.13 had some of them, but definitely not 0.10.36

Comment: I never realised this. The more you know!

Comment: Thanks guys... Kinda new to Node release cycle and all so actually this was a silly question. Sorry!